# Performance vs Readability: Local copies in functions

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
Vector2f Box::getCenter() const
{
    const float x = width / 2;
    const float y = height / 2;

    return Vector2f(x, y);
}
```

Is there a performance increase to instead write it like this:

```
Vector2f Box::getCenter() const
{
    return Vector2f(width / 2, height / 2);
}
```

I prefer the first one since it is nice and readable, but I am starting to wonder if I am losing some performance if I do this too much since it creates an extra unnecessary copy.

I know that some of you think the second function is just as readable but this is just an example, I am asking more generally and what is good coding practice in this case.

Comment: It's a near certainty that a modern C++ compiler will generate identical code in both cases. You can answer your own question all by yourself: all compilers give an option to produce machine language code instead of a binary executable. Use that option in both cases, and see if there's any difference.

Comment: Make a release build (with optimizations enabled) of both versions, and compare the generated code. My guess is that both variants would be equal.

Comment: In this case this is not an issue. In `C` and `C++` there is ["As if" rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15718279/1387438). Compiler can freely transform code to be as fast as possible as long as outcome remains unchanged. So bottom line both examples will produce exactly same machine code.

Comment: Also note that "readability" is very subjective. For an experienced programmer, both variants are probably equally readable (it is for me anyway).

Comment: I find the variables in the first a confusing diversion. They look like they're significant, but it's very difficult to guess if or how without examining the surrounding code in detail.

Comment: In fact, the second looks more readable to me.  I can immediately tell that we are halving the width and height.  For the first one, I have to store x and y to my brain registers, and then load them to interpret the return, which incurs overhead ...

Comment: @L.F. for the given example, yes, but for a more complex example, it is a great help.  Especially with good names.  `halfWidth` and `halfHeight` might be better names here, unless there is a more specific name relating to intent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a rule of thumb: Write code to be readable.

C++ as a language is designed with efficiency as one of the primary goals. In an ideal world, readable code is efficient code and c++ comes rather close to that. It is rare that you are forced to write unreadable code for performance. And even then, you should not do that right from the start. Write code for readability first always. Only when you measure you can know what is more and what is less performing.

This is a nice tool to inspect the compiler output: https://godbolt.org/ I would expect any decent compiler to emit very similar assembly when you turn on optimizations.

This is another tool that lets you easily benchmark code: http://quick-bench.com/. Don't start to optimize things before you know it makes a difference.

Compilers are rather powerful in optimizing things and most of the time they know better than you. Of course you should not do "stupid" things, e.g. clearly you wouldn't `return Vector2f(width * sin(pi/2) * exp( ln( 0.5)) , height / 2);` even though a super clever compiler could realize that it is the same as your original.

Last but not least, do not forget that you primarily write code for humans to read and understand.

**PS:** Readability is very subjective. One could argue that the second is more readable and I'd go even one step further by writing

```
Vector2f Box::getCenter() const
{
    return {width * 0.5 , height * 0.5};
}
```

This has the added benefit that you do not necessarily need to change the body if you ever decide to change the return type (or if you ever change the value type to `int`).

Comment: Excellent answer. Great to know that my compiler will optimize away stuff like this. I will continue to write it the first way without any shame :D

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, but I disagree with this for the reasons I set out in my answer.

Comment: @Oscar hum, if it came across as "write what you like and dont care" then it isnt a great answer ;). The intended message was rather: write for readability and study what your compiler does for performance

Comment: @Bathsheba I read your answer and I think there actually is no disagreement. I tried to keep the answer general (mainly pointing to tools). I added a PS that is more specific to OPs code

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 nah, it didn't come across like that. Ofcourse I'll think about performance, but it's just good to know that the general wisdom is the prioritize readability in a case like this since the optimized could would be the same.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I prefer the first one because if I have a longer function name instead of just a short variable name like `width` and `height`, and then the return statement would be so long I would have to scroll horizontally to see it all.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a code written in **C++**:

```
Vector2f GetCenterLong(float width, float height)
{
    const float x = width / 2;
    const float y = height / 2;

    return Vector2f(x, y);
}

Vector2f GetCenterShort(float width, float height)
{
    return Vector2f(width / 2, height / 2);
}
```

Here is the assembly code produced with **x64 msvc v19.21** and **-Ox** optimization.
You can notice that there is no difference between the two functions.

```
__$ReturnUdt$ = 8
width$ = 16
height$ = 24
Vector2f GetCenterLong(float,float) PROC                ; GetCenterLong
        mulss   xmm1, DWORD PTR __real@3f000000
        mov     rax, rcx
        mulss   xmm2, DWORD PTR __real@3f000000
        movss   DWORD PTR [rcx], xmm1
        movss   DWORD PTR [rcx+4], xmm2
        ret     0
Vector2f GetCenterLong(float,float) ENDP                ; GetCenterLong

__$ReturnUdt$ = 8
width$ = 16
height$ = 24
Vector2f GetCenterShort(float,float) PROC             ; GetCenterShort
        mulss   xmm1, DWORD PTR __real@3f000000
        mov     rax, rcx
        mulss   xmm2, DWORD PTR __real@3f000000
        movss   DWORD PTR [rcx], xmm1
        movss   DWORD PTR [rcx+4], xmm2
        ret     0
Vector2f GetCenterShort(float,float) ENDP             ; GetCenterShort
```

Thus, prefer readability over shortness when a compiler optimization is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are curious (and probably unintended) type-conversions then an optimising compiler will produce the same code.

The principal difference between the two is that in the first way you are potentially forcing a conversion to a `float` type.

Therefore I much prefer the second way: suppose the types for the function change to a `double` rather than the presumed `float`? That said

```
auto x = width / 2;
```

would be more acceptable.

Many debuggers these days support parameter-by-parameter evaluation, so you're not helping debugging by writing your code out the first way.

Comment: Why would it matter if the types change? It would be converted either way when passed to the constructor.

Comment: @Oscar: Imagine if `width` is refactored to a `double`, as is the type of the parameter in the function. If you forget to change the `float` then you have an unwanted truncation.

Comment: yes obviously, but it is very far fetched for that to happen since my compiler would warn me. Also I could just use `auto` instead. This was just an example

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a performance increase to instead write it like this:

Well, did you measure a performance increase? When you care about performance, always measure.

The performance can potentially be different. If the types of `width` and `height` as well as the parameters are other than `float`, then the local variables introduce two conversions, which must be performed. Performing a conversion may be slower than not performing the conversion, and it may cause a different result as well. This dependency on the type can be remedied by using `auto` type deduction.

But if we assume that there are no conversions involved, then there is no reason to assume that an optimiser couldn't produce the exactly same program in both cases, in which case the performance would be exactly the same. You can compare the assembly generated by the compiler to verify.

> I am asking more generally and what is good coding practice in this case.

Readability is more important by default. Often, and in this case as well, readability is subjective.

Performance may be more important if you measure a bottleneck, but this change is unlikely to achieve performance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `Vector2f` constructor is taking two `float`s. Then at least with an optimizing compiler you will see no difference.

If you want to know it exactly for your case you can check the compiler output (probably telling your compiler to keep the intermediate files, on gcc `-S -save-temps`) or you can check online on https://gcc.godbolt.org/.